# Gigabit WiFi on different floor

Tags: wifi, wireless

I have Asus [RT-AC1200G+](https://www.asus.com/Networking/RT-AC1200G-Plus/) router downstairs with my home media server connected with cable (Video streaming, NAS, VM streaming).

On ground floor WiFi reception is very good (144MBit on 2,4 and over 350MBit on 5GHz).
On second floor I have poor signal (unstable 60-80MBit on 2.4, very unstable 15MBit on 5GHz).

What I want to have ground-floor quality signal on second floor.

Router repositioning isn't an option - this is where internet cable is.
Normally I would lay additional ethernet cable to upstairs and buy a good access point - but property owner strictly forbids doing it on my own and he demands ~250$ for it (+cable&AP price of course).
House is pretty old, so PLC adaptor probably isn't a solution (however I haven't tested it yet).

My question: is there a better solution than paying an owner to lay an ethernet cable for me and buy AP?

Comment: Is a range extender an option? You didn't mention latency.

Comment: @Alpha3031: Low latency is wanted (VM streaming), but not crucial. I have never tested range extender when high speeds were needed...

Comment: if you have cable on the ground floor and second floor you can try ethernet over cable.

Comment: How much do you want to save for you to consider the latency difference worth it? And do you have any access point in mind? I've found a few options, but they come to $125 at the very minimum.

Comment: @Alpha3031: well, I was thinking of buying another RT-AC1200G+ (~80$) which also works in access point mode, but any ideas are welcome. I was talking to the owner and he agreed that I can put the cable myself so the biggest expense goes away.

Comment: If you want a ground-floor quality signal on your second floor, an ethernet cable to another RT-AC1200G is really the only way to go (and cheapest). Especially so now that your landlord has agreed to allow you to lay a cable. Otherwise I would suggest linking 2 RT-AC1200Gs over powerline ethernet.